# Codimension of ideal generated by regular sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm thinking this question: Suppose $(f_1,\dots,f_r)$ is a regular sequence of the polynomial ring $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ where $k$ is a field (not necessary but one can assume $k$ is algebraically closed). Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $f_1,\dots,f_r$, is it true that $$\mathrm{codim}~I = r\ ?$$ I don't quite believe it but I cannot give a counterexample. If it is true, I'll be really happy to see a proof.

Comment: What happens if you take $f_i = x_i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by $\mathrm{codim}~I$ you mean $\operatorname{ht}I$, then yes. More general, if $R$ is a commutative noetherian ring and $f_1,\dots,f_r$ is a regular sequence, then $\operatorname{ht}(f_1,\dots,f_r)=r$. One ca prove this by induction on $r$. The main step (which I leave you as an exercise) is to show that $\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak p/(f)=\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak p-1$ where $f$ is a non-zerodivisor on $R$ which belongs to a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: By using Krull principal thm, I proved this. Thanks for the help. Is the converse also true BTW?

Comment: What converse are you referring to? The converse of your claim about height of $I$?

Comment: Basically yes. Sorry for the ambiguity of the comment, because I'm also thinking of it. Off the top of my head, I think my question should be, if a sequence $f_1,\cdots,f_r$ satisfies that $\mathrm{ht}(f_1,\cdots,f_r)=r$, is this a regular sequence? For $r=1$ case, we probably need $R$ to be reduced. Further than this, I have no idea now.

Comment: Obviously, not without extra hypotheses. If $R$ is a Cohen-Macaulay local ring, then the claim holds for any $r\ge1$.